# create user with self-specified uid

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am using flutter with firebase to manage my users, and in this link, it says you can specify the uid during user creation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user

**My question:** What's the equivalent in dart/ flutter? I understand firebase auto-generates one for you, but in my use case I need to be able to specify mine.

For flutter, I am only aware of **createUserWithEmailAndPassword** method but it does not have a '**uid**' argument.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: null, password: null)
```

In the link above, however, they provided an example (**node.js**) with such methods.

```
admin.auth().createUser({
  uid: 'some-uid',
  email: 'user@example.com',
  phoneNumber: '+11234567890'
})
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
  });
```

Comment: I answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77589981/13454881

Answer (score 2):

You can fully control the creation of Firebase Authentication users by implementing a custom provider. But as you can probably imagine, this is a sensitive operation, so the code requires that you have full administrative access to the Firebase project. For that reason, you can't run this type of operation in your Flutter app, but must run it on a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions.

Typically this means:

1. you'll gather the user's credentials in your Flutter app
2. send them (securely) to a custom endpoint on the server
3. and there validate the the user credentials are correct
4. and use the [Admin SDK to create a token for the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens)
5. that you then send back securely to the Flutter app

Comment: Just trying to get my head around this, will the Client SDK then still manage refreshing of the token on the client as normal once logged in with the token returned to it on step 5?

Comment: For custom providers you will have to handle token refresh yourself, as the SDK has no way of knowing how to refresh the token that you minted.

Comment: I have followed your steps, thanks first of all, it has helped me solve my problem of using a UID given to me from another server,  and to get my rules to check for ".. if request.auth != null". Maybe my question wasn't clear, I wanted to know if the token received from firebase that is now used in Flutter, will auto refresh in the app, as it does when you use the normal firebase auth from the client. I am now using signInWithCustomToken(token_response) to sign in.

Comment: "thanks first of all" -> upvotes appreciated 
The above scenario results in a custom token, and those are not auto-refreshed by the client-side SDK as it has no way of knowing how to refresh the token that was minted by the server-side code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What is the best approach to refresh this token process in flutter? Getting a bit lost in all the docs. Never done this before (I now realise how the firebase auth service makes life so much easier than doing this manually)

Comment: I had to double check with the team, and I actually was wrong earlier. It turns out that when you call `signInWithCustomToken(token)` on the client, the SDK does refresh the ID token automatically every hour.

Comment: Frank, thank you, so much. I really appreciate you asking them, this means allot to me at this point of the project. 

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option for any of the Firebase the client SDKs on any platform (Android, iOS, web, Flutter, etc).

Firebase Admin is a server SDK, and trusts that the code calling its methods is privileged and running in a secure and trusted environment.  This is considered to be safe for inventing UIDs.  The client SDKs are run on user devices, which is considered untrusted and could be compromised.  In that case, the Firebase Auth product has to come up with an appropriate UID for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Use the firebase cloud functions

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.createUser1 = functions.https.onCall(async (data, _context) => {
  try {
    const user = await admin.auth().createUser({
      uid: data.uid,
      phoneNumber: data.phoneNumber,
      disabled: false,
    }); return {response: user};
  } catch (error) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("failed to create a user");
  }
});
```

then request from flutter app

```
{
    "data":
    {
        "uid": "12345678",
        "phoneNumber": "+905378227777",
        "disabled": false
    }
}
```