# how to create FireBase new users with custom UID with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I've been trying to create a new user in firebase with a custom UID in flutter, but it seems it only can be done using FireBaseAdmin package, and it hasn't been implemented yet in flutter. Is there's any possible way to create a new user with custom UID?

I have no background on native development, so it's not possible for me to implement the admin methods in native java or kotlin in the current time. any one has an idea on how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

The UID for a user is determine by the authentication provider that creates the user. There is no way to specify your own UID when calling to the existing providers in the client-side Firebase SDKs (such as the FlutterFire libraries).

If specifying your own UID for a user is a hard requirement, you can [implement a custom provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth). This *does* involve writing code to [create a custom ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) that runs in a trusted environment (such as your development machine, a server that you control, or Cloud Functions) however.

Alternatively, you can also consider storing a mapping from Firebase-provided UID to the ID that you want to use to refer to that same user. This is a scenario regularly used to give users a unique name, so I recommend checking out [questions related to unique user names](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+unique+user+name).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i do it. I use firebase cloud functions and normal firebase auth package from pub.dev.

In the app, at the time of login, i submit the user's email address and uid to the server via an http trigger firebase function and the http package (also available on pub.dev). Here's the code.

```
 Future<String?> createAccountWithSpecificUserID(
String? email,
String? userName,
String? password,
String uid,
String? phone,
) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(
        '${cloudFunctionStart}createFirebaseUser',
      ),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: jsonEncode(
        {
          if (email != null) 'email': email,
          if (userName != null) "username": userName,
          if (password != null) 'password': password,
          'uid': uid,
          if (phone != null) "phone": phone,
        },
      ),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return response.body;
    }
  }
```

and this function sends the data to the cloud function whose code is like this (it's in typescript. Feel free to use it as you need):

```
export const createFirebaseUser = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    corsMiddleware(req, res, async () => {
        try {
            const email = req.body.email;
            const password = req.body.password;
            const name = req.body.name;
            const uid = req.body.uid;

            const userRecord = await admin.auth().createUser({
                email: email,
                displayName: name,
                uid: uid,
                emailVerified: false,
                password: password,
                disabled: false,
            });

            res.status(200).send(`User created with email: ${userRecord.email}`);
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).send(`Error creating user: ${error}`);

            logToConsole("Error creating user", error!.toString(), error);
        }
    });
});
```

Aand this function returns a nullable string. If the string is null, then we're good. Sign in. IF not, then there was an error and the string is the error message.  Here's a code sample

```
setState(() {
                    processing = true;
                    nameController = TextEditingController(
                      text: accts[0].name,
                    );
                    processingText = translation(context)!.creatingAccount;
                  });

                  if (nameController.text.trim().isEmpty) {
                    nameController = TextEditingController(
                      text: accts[0].name,
                    );
                  }

                  String? cc = await createAccountWithSpecificUserID(
                    emailController.text.trim().toLowerCase(),
                    nameController.text.trim(),
                    passwordController.text.trim(),
                    accts[0].id,
                    null,
                  );

                  if (cc == null) {
                    signIn();
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      processing = false;
                    });

                    showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) {
                        return CustomDialogBox(
                          bodyText:
                              "$cc.\n\n${translation(context)!.ifYouNeedHelp}",
                          buttonText: translation(context)!.pressHereToCallUs,
                          onButtonTap: () {
                            context.pushNamed(
                              RouteConstants.contactUs,
                            );
                          },
                          showButton: true,
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
```

I hope this helps.
Oh also, that `translation(context). blah blah` stuff is just my translated strings. I had to add localization to the code coz the app is used by people that speak different languages.

Answer (score -1):

You can use FirebaseAuthentication.

When a user create an account it will create a new user with a random UID and the UID will be unique. I assume that you can also specify you own UIDs

Here is the link : https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/

Its very easy to use :p

Comment: So you made an answer with an assumption without checking it first...?